# How to pass data from js into html still in js

Tags: javascript, html

Due to the structure of my project I have to define my modal's markup in js.
To do so I write:
`var modal_message = '<ul><li id="address"></li><li id="average"></li></ul>';`
However, I need to pass inside this html markup some js variables from my code.

It's kind of `$('#address').innerHTML = var1;
$('#average_sum').innerHTML = var2;`
But this doesnot work as the modal is defined only after clicking a button. So I wanna pre-pass all the variables in the way `<li>{{ var1 }}</li>`
What should I do to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a temporary element with the HTML content.

**Using JQuery** :

```js
let modal_message = '<ul><li id="address"></li><li id="average"></li></ul>';


// create a dummy element with your html
var $temp = $('<div/>', {
  html: modal_message
})

let var1= 'test', var2 = 'test1';


// get elements and update html content
$temp.find('#address ').html(var1);
$temp.find('#average').html(var2);

// now get the dummy element html content
console.log($temp.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Without JQuery** :

```js
let modal_message = '<ul><li id="address"></li><li id="average"></li></ul>';

// create a dummy dom element
var $temp = document.createElement('div');
// set HTML content
$temp.innerHTML = modal_message;

let var1 = 'test',
  var2 = 'test1';

// get elements within dummy element and update content
$temp.querySelector('#address ').innerHTML = var1;
$temp.querySelector('#average').innerHTML = var2;

// get final html content
console.log($temp.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

In case there is only one parent tag in your HTML string then there is no need to create a dummy element instead just use the string.

```js
let modal_message = '<ul><li id="address"></li><li id="average"></li></ul>';


// create a jQuery element with your html
var $temp = $(modal_message)

let var1= 'test', var2 = 'test1';


// get elements and update html content
$temp.find('#address ').html(var1);
$temp.find('#average').html(var2);

// now get the outerHTML property of current element
console.log($temp.prop('outerHTML'));
// or 
console.log($temp[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var modal_message = `<ul><li id="address">${var1}</li><li id="average">${var2}</li></ul>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using template [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
var content = "Hello World!";
var template = `<p>${content}</p>`;
$('#stuff').html(template);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stuff"></div>
```